# Stats is not exported by node_modules error - Rollup

Tags: javascript, rollup

I'm trying to add stats.js ( a little fps counter ) to my three.js scene. The project uses rollup to bundle everything and I keep getting this error after trying to import Stats like so:

```
import { Stats } from 'stats.js'
```

The error reads:

```
[!] Error: 'Stats' is
not exported by node_modules\stats.js\build\stats.min.js, imported by src\main.js
```

My rollup config looks like this:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'; // locate and bundle dependencies in node_modules (mandatory)
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser"; // code minification (optional)

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: [
        {
            format: 'umd',
            name: 'LIB',
            file: 'build/main.js'
        }
    ],
    plugins: [ resolve(), terser() ]
};
```

Stats is exported in stats.js like this:

```
export { Stats as default };
```

I keep scrolling through bug reports on github and i'm unsure if they relate or not - getting confused - does anyone have a clue?

EDIT: based in the initial answer, I tried using:

```
import * as Stats from 'stats.js'
```

i get the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Stats' of undefined
```

referencing this line:

```
(function(f,e){"object"===typeof exports&&"undefined"!==typeof module?module.exports=e():"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define(e):f.Stats=e();})(undefined,function(){var f=function(){function e(a){c.appendChild(a.dom);return a}function u(a){for(var d=0;d<c.children.length;d++)c.children[d].style.display=d===a?"block":"none";l=a;}var l=0,c=document.createElement("div");c.style.cssText="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;cursor:pointer;opacity:0.9;z-index:10000";c.addEventListener("click",function(a){a.preventDefault();
```

__

I tried:

```
const Stats = require('stats-js');
```

and got the error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

__

I tried:

```
import Stats from 'stats-js'
```

and got this:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
stats-js (imported by src\main.js)(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
stats-js (guessing 'Stats')
```

I sounds like this last error is the most useful? I followed the link in the error message but still can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

That library doesn’t provide an es6 default export.

```
import * as Stats from 'stats-js'
// or
const Stats = require('stats-js')
// or
import Stats from 'stats-js'
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to read up more to be able to tell the difference in exports in the future. However, none of these methods seemed to work. I will update my question showing error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error to yours, but I found the reason and used the following code when importing

```
import {} from 'Stats.js'
```

(sorry for using a translator)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs an answer, try importing Stats without the curly braces:

```js
import Stats from "three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js";
```